# Evernote printer for linux

Tags: evernote

I am looking for evrenote printer. Same idea as PDF printer. Whenever you print anything it sends it to ever note.

Comment: it can be a more generalized thing share or cloud printer, where one of the choices is evernote.

Comment: It looks like this can be done with Google Cloud Print: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794179

Answer (score 0):

Nevernote is an open source clone of Evernote. The program, coded in Java, is able to run on Linux, Windows, and OS-X, but the primary goal is to provide a Linux client.

Nevernote was recently renamed to NixNote and comes in .deb packages for both 32 bit and 64 bit systems, available on the developer’s website.

http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/